# Comments moderation queue view from django.contrib.comments - gone in 1.2?

Tags: django, django-comments

I've happily used the neat comment moderation queue view supplied with contrib.comments in 1.0.x, but recently thought I'd use it in a Django 1.2 site, only to discover that the view is no longer there (no longer referenced in contrib.comments.urls, for example)

Two questions:
When did it disappear?
Why did it disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it was removed as a result of [this ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11625) about a year ago. The notes on that ticket state that the view was to be removed because it was undocumented, and the identical functionality is now available as admin actions on the main comments changelist view.